Looker Data Studio drill through link not allow params in the url?
I have question related to looker studio.
I have the following Looker Dashboard URL:
https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/da288ce1-ef15-4cef-aefb-c52acff4045f/page/FkV9D?params=%7B%22tdviewby%22:%22sector%22,%22tdquery%22:%22school%22%7D

as you can see from the URL above, i have installed 2 parameters:

tdviewby
tdquery

Here's the table chart for an example:

What i want is when a user click on SCHOOL they will be redirected to:
https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/da288ce1-ef15-4cef-aefb-c52acff4045f/page/FkV9D?params=%7B%22tdviewby%22:%22sector%22,%22tdquery%22:%22school%22%7D
when a user click on shoes they will be redirected to:
https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/da288ce1-ef15-4cef-aefb-c52acff4045f/page/FkV9D?params=%7B%22tdviewby%22:%22sector%22,%22tdquery%22:%22shoes%22%7D
the problem is looker data studio won't allow any params in the URL. I tried to fill the following URL:
https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/da288ce1-ef15-4cef-aefb-c52acff4045f/page/FkV9D?params=%7B%22tdviewby%22:%22sector%22,%22tdquery%22:%22school%22%7D it shows error as follow:

when i remove the params, it showed no error.

the save button is enabled.
how do i resolve this?
